# Holoviews plot with horizontal scrollbar?

Tags: python, plot, bokeh, holoviews, hvplot

I would like to realize a holoviews plot with a scrollbar for the time/x axis.

In detail, I want to plot a long ecg signal (20 minutes) and be able to display a frame of e.g. 10 seconds with the possibility to scroll along the entire signal.

Is there a way to realize this? Thank you!

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiF9J.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two options you should know about.

**1. Option**

Enable the scrolling by mouse.
For this you have to activate the tool [`xwheel_pan`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html?highlight=xwheel_pan#wheelpantool) for your figure.

See this very basic example:

```py
import numpy as np
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('bokeh')

x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, 100)
y = np.sin(x)
scatter = hv.Scatter((x, y), label='sin(x)').opts(
        tools=['xwheel_pan'], 
        active_tools=['xwheel_pan']
    )
scatter
```

In this example the tool is also activated by default. Using the wheel of the mouse will result in an action like this.

[image: xwheel_pan in action]

**2. Option**

Add a second figure and a [`RangeTool`](http://holoviews.org/gallery/demos/bokeh/timeseries_range_tool.html).

This example needs some more lines of code:

```
import numpy as np
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import opts
from holoviews.plotting.links import RangeToolLink
hv.extension('bokeh')

x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, 100)
y = np.sin(x)
scatter = hv.Scatter((x, y), label='sin(x)').opts(width=300, height=300)
selection = hv.Scatter((x, y)).opts(width=300, height=100, yaxis=None, default_tools=[])

RangeToolLink(selection, scatter)
layout = (scatter + selection).cols(1)
layout.opts(opts.Layout(shared_axes=False, merge_tools=False))
```

[image: range tool in action]

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed answer, it works fine for me!